# In C, how to malloc and free a SOCKET (already a pointer)

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, winsock

the `SOCKET` is from `winsock.h`

Declared as

```
SOCKET BillerSocket;
```

As far as I know `SOCKET` is already a pointer in disguise, so I shouldn't do `free(*BillerSocket);`.

I `malloc` it with

```
BillerSocket = malloc(sizeof(SOCKET));
```

I get this warning

**[Warning] assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]**

When I `free` a SOCKET with

```
free(BillerSocket);
```

I get a warning and a Note which seems to tell me what I have to do.

**[Warning] passing argument 1 of 'free' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]**

```
129 0   c:\program files\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\combaseapi.h    In file included from c:\program files\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\combaseapi.h
14      c:\program files\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\objbase.h                    from c:\program files\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\objbase.h
17      c:\program files\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ole2.h                   from c:\program files\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ole2.h
12      c:\program files\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\wtypes.h                     from c:\program files\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\wtypes.h
10      c:\program files\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\winscard.h                   from c:\program files\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\winscard.h
97      c:\program files\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\windows.h                    from c:\program files\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\windows.h
1       main.c       
            from main.c
438 16  c:\program files\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\stdlib.h
```

**[Note] expected 'void *' but argument is of type 'SOCKET'**

How do I remove the warnings?

Comment: You don't malloc and free, you use `socket()` and `closesocket()`.

Comment: Also, `SOCKET` is not a pointer.

Comment: oh thanks I never use C/C++ just came time to use it and I wanted to clear the warnings, Thanks for the Tips, I'll remove `malloc` and `free`. If you want you could write a answer and I'll accept it, or I could delete the question but it might help some people out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at `winsock.h` more closely, you will see that `SOCKET` is not a pointer, it is an integer:

```
typedef UINT_PTR SOCKET;
```

`UINT_PTR` is not a pointer to a `UINT` (`PUINT` and `LPUINT` are). It is a `UINT` that is the same size as a pointer.  So `UINT_PTR` is 4 bytes in a 32bit process and is 8 bytes in a 64bit process.  See MSDN's documentation for more details on that:

[Windows Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx)

> UINT_PTR 
>   An unsigned INT_PTR.
>
> This type is declared in BaseTsd.h as follows:
>
> ```
> #if defined(_WIN64)
>  typedef unsigned __int64 UINT_PTR;
> #else
>  typedef unsigned int UINT_PTR;
> #endif
> ```

You do not use `malloc()` and `free()` to manage `SOCKET` values, you have to use `socket()` and `closesocket()` instead:

```
SOCKET BillerSocket;
...
BillerSocket = socket(...);
...
closesocket(BillerSocket);
```

Comment: It doesn't even matter what type `SOCKET` is. It is opaque to the application.